# Django tastypie advanced filtering

Tags: python, django, filter, tastypie

I'm trying to implement an advanced filter in my Resource but i need some help to built and apply my own filters.
The goal is to get filters info in my api UserResource before to get objects list through an url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/list/&orderby="gender"&limit=10
```

Actually, my resource looks like this:

```
class UserResource(Resource):

   firstName = fields.CharField(attribute='firstName')
   lastName = fields.CharField(attribute='lastName')
   gender= fields.CharField(attribute='gender')
   status= fields.IntegerField(attribute='status')
   date= fields.DateTimeField(attribute='date')

   class Meta:
       resource_name = 'users/list'
       object_class = dict2obj
       authorization = Authorization()

   def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
       kwargs = {}
       if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
           kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.firstName
       else:
           kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.firstName
       return kwargs

   def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
       db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx',user='test2',passwd='xxx',db='mydb')
       cur = db.cursor()
       cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users order by gender Desc limit 0,10")
       users=cur.fetchall()
       #...
       db.close()
       return posts
```

I would like to know how to get filters info to return my obj list.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use MySQLdb directly and not django ORM ?

Comment: yes because I'm carrying out a project which aims to provide stats data through api in json format and data belongs to another application, which is linked to these sql databases...